# Is there any vector drawing applcations that the origin of coordinate system is top left corner?

Tags: software-recommendation, applications

I've been using Inkscape, but the origin is at the bottom left corner, and I can't seem to change it to the top left corner.

GIMP's origin is at top left corner, but GIMP is not a vector drawing program.

So, my question is, ***is there a vector program that set the origin of the canvas at top left corner of screen?***

---

***Edits (for clarification)***

Thanks for the comments and answers, apparently, I did not clarify my purpose of wanting such an application.

I am currently making real-time animations by using an animation engine, written by someone else, which uses (0,0) at the top left corner of the screen. I don't mind doing mental manipulations from Inkscape on a small number of vector objects, but I am dealing with a lot of objects that need to be animated externally which require me to supply coordinate system that differs from Inkscape.

---

Comment: why would it matter? I mean its a pretty trivial transformation.

Comment: To speed up my workflow.

Comment: Ok, could you describe the benefits for you, and how it becomes a benefit. Thete is no reason why your workflow could not be sped up without canging the origin of the software. in illustrator and photoshop you can move the ruler origin.

Comment: I mean you should edit the post to describe the benefits, how they come into your workflow and at what stage you expect the coordinates to be in this fashion. Like i said illustrator GUI already works from top left corner or whatever point you want really. But its better if you descibe the workflow benefit as then somebody might describe something even better.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14013/discussion-between-joojaa-and-johnb)

Comment: Illustrator CS4+ has the origin in the top left corner. <=CS3 has it in the bottom left. But you can change it with a manual preference file edit.

Comment: @jooja I am working with a real-time animation package written by someone else which uses (0,0) at the top left corner of the screen. I don't mind doing mental manipulations on a small number of objects, but I am dealing with a lot of objects that must be animated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are under the impression that moving the origin to the top left of your canvas lets you work with coordinates where (10,10) is ten to the right and ten down. But it doesn't work that way. Let me explain:

The output of vector applications are points and paths. They are plotted on a coordinate system. The coordinate system used reflects the specification of the output file. Most vector applications are developed to generate Postscript files.

The 'default' origin in the Postscript coordinate system is bottom left. This is because your canvas will be in the positive quadrant of the coordinate system. Working with positive values is easiest.

Some software let you move the origin. If you place the origin of a Postscript file to the top left of the canvas, then the y-values of points on that canvas will be negative. That is because the canvas is now the bottom right quadrant. So moving the origin will technically change a thing. To move a point up/down you still need to add/subtract units of the y-value. It doesn't matter which quadrant you're in. Adding a unit moves a point up, subtracting a unit moves a point down.

[image]

Long story short. The type of data you wish to generate defines the coordinate system. Don't fight it, or try to change it. Try to understand it. Work with it.

Comment: The *output format* and the coordinate system *you work with* do not have to be the same.  A vector illustration program could easily provide a canvas with (0, 0) at the top-left with a rightward positive x-axis and a downward positive y-axis and then do a trivial translation when generating output files.

Answer (score 1):

To recap some of the discussions. **Inkscape** measures from bottom left, with up is positive standard mathematical notation, and standard postscript (this will be changed to unify it with the internal SVG Y axis - see this [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/170049)). **Illustrator** uses a GUI standard top, left, y coordinates positive is down.

You can not change the setting in *Inkscape*. But i am pointing out, that you dont need to change the setting to gain this benefit. All you need to have is a custom panel that shows you a transformed coordinate. Or change cords at export etc. This is reasonable since your not actually reading the underlying coordinates anyway (your reading world coordinates and the locals are transformed anyway). This should be pretty trivial to implement.

If you really rely on changing definitions which probably would break quite a lot of code (eg. cross product and would now result in opposite answer). In any case there's something wrong with the approach anyway. Have to download inkscape to test the panel idea. But I dont know if this helps to the OP as there's no description of where the problem is except changing coordinate which does really not do anything useful since your not viewing internal machine state anyway.

Comment: Illustrator CS5 and up have the origin at the top left to match other Adobe products. Before 5 the origin was at the bottom left.

Comment: @allcaps yes i was wondering about that actually because i could remember it was bottom. But yes i found the preference Scott mentioned and it cleared things up.

Comment: @joojaa I added clarification in my question.